# How to handle overthinking and being nervous all the time

Tags: mental-health, brain, depression, anxiety-disorders, mental-exhaustion

I'm an application developer with little experience. I recently graduated from university and now I work as a app/game developer. My issue is that every time I get a new task or project I get very nervous because it's something new and something I didn't do before, and this makes me lose focus, waste time and prevents me from being creative in my field. Also when I get project assigned to me on a weekend and I need start it in the beginning of the week, I keep wasting time over thinking about and being nervous which causes me to stay desperate and negative. How can I overcome this fear and accept the challenges and just keep stuff simple in my head?

Comment: I think this question is asking for an individualised treatement/diagnostic. But for what it's worth, I have read Feeling Good: The New Mood Therapy by David D. Burns. He addresses some of your concerns.

Comment: Actually there should be behavior change, try CBT and let me know the result